New Solana Dev Here: Can someone please point me to the latest up-to-date education content?

Problem - I've spent 2 weeks already going through buildspace and soldev.app and have come across "broken" material.

Details and research - Has code not been maintained?  Things seem to be breaking.

What I've tried - Buildspace "Build a Solana + Rust App" and soldev.app dAPP (Stuck at Interact with Wallet module"


Am I using old content? Is there somewhere with updated content?

You're right, there's a huge amount of Solana content that's out of date. There's a variety of reasons for this:

New versions of Solana CLI, Anchor, Metaplex, node, and new features and bugs
The 'chewing glass' ideology that learning Solana should be painful
The false idea that once content has been created, the content keeps working

...have made learning Solana difficult. Things should just work, and far too often: they don't. Solana Foundation Dev Ecosystem know we can do better and are working hard to do so.

The Solana Course (at https://soldev.app) - we've just rewritten all the frontend portion of the course, and we're about to completely rewrite the on-chain development portion of the course to focus on Anchor. I'll update this answer again once that's complete. You can (and should) file a bug for anything that doesn't work. We do respond to filed issues.

The most up to date content is in the Professional Education repo which is a cut down, focused set of of content covering everything from cryptography basics to your first on-chain app. This has a slightly different purpose than the course - it's designed for instructor-based training - is up to date as of this week. Every version of Solana CLI, node, Anchor, Metaplex, etc. is specified, every piece of code works, there are instructor notes with diagrams and animations, and working solutions for every lab. The content is here is being ported back to the Solana Course as we speak (and I'll update this answer when that is done), in the meantime you can follow the instructor notes for a battle-tested guide to Solana Development. Specifically it looks like you want to learn onchain development - skip to Lesson 6: Intro to Anchor. Again you can expected this same content to appear in the Course too.


